# how to hide <li> bullets in navigation menu and footer links BUT show them for listing items

Tags: html, html-lists

I have a navigation menu, footer, and a slideshow which use listed style to list links and images. I have the css `list-style:none;` set to hide the bullets next to the links and images in the nav and footer but I want to show the bullets for list normal text.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use a specific selector for the navigation's `<li>` items, which contains a valid [`list-style-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/list-style-type) property (`none` to hide).

Comment: could you give me an example?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The example bellow explains how to remove bullets using a css style class.
You can use , similar to css class, by identifier (#id), by parent tag, etc.
The same way you can use to define a css to remove bullets from the page footer.

I've used [this site](http://w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp) as a starting point.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div.ui-menu li {
    list-style:none;
    background-image:none;
    background-repeat:none;
    background-position:0; 
}
ul
{
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
li
{
    background-image:url(sqpurple.gif);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0px 5px; 
    padding-left:14px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="ui-menu">
<ul>
<li>Coffee</li>
<li>Tea</li>
<li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
</div>

<ul>
<li>Coffee</li>
<li>Tea</li>
<li>Coca Cola</li>
</ul>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This worked for me in my latest effort to style a WordPress child theme. But in this case there was also a ::before specified, which made a bullet out of a 3px border out of a point. That also had some padding. So when employing something like this, just give a glance if there are other competing CSS styles.

Answer (score 46):

You need to define a class for the bullets you want to hide. For examples

```css
.no-bullets {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

Then apply it to the list you want hidden bullets:

```
<ul class="no-bullets">
```

All other lists (without a specific class) will show the bulltets as usual.

Answer (score 7):

You can style `li` elements differently based on their `class`, their `id` or their ancestor elements:

```css
li { /* styles all li elements*/
    list-style-type: none;
}

#ParentListID li { /* styles the li elements that have an ancestor element
                      of id="ParentListID" */
    list-style-type: bullet;
}

li.className { /* styles li elements of class="className" */
    list-style-type: bullet;
}
```

Or, to use the ancestor elements:

```css
#navigationContainerID li { /* specifically styles the li elements with an ancestor of
                               id="navigationContainerID" */
    list-style-type: none;
}

li { /* then styles all other li elements that don't have that ancestor element */
    list-style-type: bullet;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

when bullet have to hide then use:

`li { list-style: none;}`

when bullet have to list show, then use:

`li { list-style: initial;}`

Comment: Appreciate your reply.  In case you want to add some formatting to your replies,  can use this guide [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you're using this HTML5 layout:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav><ul>...</ul></nav>
        </header>
        <article>
            <ul>...</ul>
        </article>
        <footer>
            <ul>...</ul>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

You could say in your CSS:

```css
header ul, footer ul, nav ul { list-style-type: none; }
```

If you're using HTML 4, assign IDs to your DIVs (instead of using the new fancy-pants elements) and change this to:

```css
#header ul, #footer ul, #nav ul { list-style-type: none; }
```

If you're using a CSS reset stylesheet (like Eric Meyer's), you would actually have to give the list style back, since the reset removes the list style from all lists.

```css
#content ul { list-style-type: disc; margin-left: 1.5em; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I combined some of [Flavio's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10488130/2932052) to this **small solution**.

```
.hidden-ul-bullets li {
    list-style: none;
}
.hidden-ul-bullets ul {
    margin-left: 0.25em; // for my purpose, a little indentation is wished
}
```

The decision about bullets is made at an enclosing element, typically a `div`. The **drawback** (or todo) of my solution is that the liststyle removal also applies to ordered lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define a class for the bullets you want to *show*, so in the CSS:

```
ul {list-style:none; list-style-type:none; list-style-image:none;}
```

And in the HTML you just define which lists to show:

```
<ul style="list-style:disc;">
```

Or you alternatively define a CSS class:

```
.show-list {list-style:disc;}
```

Then apply it to the list you want to show:

```
<ul class="show-list">
```

All other lists won't show the bullets...