# RMarkdown with knitr to HTML: How to hide bullets in TOC (table of contents)?

Tags: html, r, knitr, r-markdown, tableofcontents

How can I **suppress the bullet points in front of the TOC items** in the created HTML file? I want to see only the headline numbers...

Example **Test.Rmd** file:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "01/25/2015"
output:
  html_document:
    number_sections: true
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
---

*Content*

# Headline 1
## Sub headline 1.1
## Sub headline 1.2
### Sub sub headline 1.2.1
# Headline 2
```

The **TOC of the resulting HTML document** will look like this (with the unwanted bullet points - here indicated via the * char):

```
Untitled
Author

01/25/2015

* 1 Headline 1
  * 1.1 Sub headline 1.1
  * 1.2 Sub headline 1.2
    * 1.2.1 Sub sub headline 1.2.1
* 2 Headline 2
...
```

The reason for bullet points is the li tag that knitr uses with the default HTML template. The **created HTML code** looks like this:

```
<div id="TOC">
<ul>
<li><a href="#headline-1"><span class="toc-section-number">1</span> Headline 1</a><ul>
<li><a href="#sub-headline-1.1"><span class="toc-section-number">1.1</span> Sub headline 1.1</a></li>
<li><a href="#sub-headline-1.2"><span class="toc-section-number">1.2</span> Sub headline 1.2</a><ul>
<li><a href="#sub-sub-headline-1.2.1"><span class="toc-section-number">1.2.1</span> Sub sub headline 1.2.1</a></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="#headline-2"><span class="toc-section-number">2</span> Headline 2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I read a little bit about **CSS** to suppress bullet points but I have no idea to solve this issue:

[how to hide <li> bullets in navigation menu and footer links BUT show them for listing items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487908/how-to-hide-li-bullets-in-navigation-menu-and-footer-links-but-show-them-for-l)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put this in `styles.css`:

```
div#TOC li {
    list-style:none;
    background-image:none;
    background-repeat:none;
    background-position:0;
}
```

And then use this in the Rmd header YAML:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "01/25/2015"
output:
  html_document:
    css: styles.css
    number_sections: true
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
---
```

That will give you the #'s but no •'s. NOTE: `styles.css` and your Rmd file need to be in the same directory.

Comment: Does work as requested, thx!
As an add-on- wish: I would like to avoid additional files but include the CSS in the Rmd file so that everything (text, pictures and layout) is contained in one file. I found out how using the content of your styles.css (just copy the content of the styles.css into the Rmd file itself and you get rid of the styles.css file). I post a second answer with this solution

Answer (score 2):

If you want to avoid having an additional (css) file besides the HTML file you can put the CSS code into your Rmd file directly:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Author"
date: "01/25/2015"
output:
  html_document:
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
---

<style type="text/css">
div#TOC li {
    list-style:none;
    background-image:none;
    background-repeat:none;
    background-position:0; 
}
</style>
Your content starts here...
```