# R Markdown task list as on GitHub

Tags: r, github, r-markdown

Is it possible to make task list as on GitHub using R Markdown?

GitHub use.

```
- [x] @mentions, #refs, [links](), **formatting**, and <del>tags</del> are supported
- [x] list syntax is required (any unordered or ordered list supported)
- [x] this is a complete item
- [ ] this is an incomplete item
```

Comment: The CSS is [highly customizable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138456/rmarkdown-with-knitr-to-html-how-to-hide-bullets-in-toc-table-of-contents) so it should be doable