# Dots appearing in nav bar in firefox?

Tags: html, css

I made a navigation bar on chrome and it works fine. However, on firefox a dot appears infront of every nav tab. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? It's really not a big deal, but if I can fix it I will try and fix it. Thanks for your help in advance and have a great day!

[image: This image demonstrates the situation:]

This is the code I'm using:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Blitz</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Stylesheet.CSS">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico">
<body background="http://blog.jimdo.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/tree-247122.jpg">
<header>
<div class="Nav">
    <h2><center><strong>Blitz</strong></center></h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home |</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Forums |</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog |</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us |</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Info </a></li>
    </ul>

</div>
</header>


</body>

</html>





/*CSS script*/


body{
margin:0;
padding:0;

}

.Nav{
margin:0 auto;
width:75%;
height:auto;
background:#A7EAFC;
overflow:auto;
border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.Nav ul li{
float:left;
}

.Nav a{
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    color:black;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family: Arial sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.Nav a:hover{
color:blue;
text-decoration:underline;

}
```

Comment: They look like bullets to me.  You may have to find a place for: list-style-type: none

Comment: oh! I thought for sure I already had that on none. Sorry for my silly error! I will accept answer as soon as possible! Sorry folks!

Comment: Missing `</head>` tag

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to hide <li> bullets in navigation menu and footer links BUT show them for listing items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487908/how-to-hide-li-bullets-in-navigation-menu-and-footer-links-but-show-them-for-l)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this rule to your CSS:

```
.Nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}
```

Comment: The HTML in your question is also missing a closing `</head>` tag.

Comment: Oh, I must of deleted it by accident. Thanks for the help, i'll accept answer asap.

Comment: No problem! Just figured I'd give you a heads up.